# What T-SQL is being executed by my LINQ-to-SQL queries?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is there any easy way to find out what T-SQL is being generated by my LINQ-to-SQL query?

Preferably using some LINQ entrypoint, rather than a licenced software product like *Microsoft SQL Server Profiler* or *LINQ-to-SQL Profiler*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) property of DataContext class. Here is an example: [DataContext.Log - Logging LINQ To SQL Output to Console or Debugger Output Window](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/08/17/DataContextLogLoggingLINQToSQLOutputConsoleDebuggerOuputWindow.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Linq-to-SQL query in your C# code, just debug into your app and hover the mouse over the variable that takes the results - you should be able to inspect the actual SQL being used by that Linq-to-SQL query.

[image]

See fullsize image:  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=okudf7&s=5

Comment: You can see even more details with LINQ Query Visualizer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629285.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Call the Query's `ToString()` Method.

As long as the resultset is `IQueryable<T>`, the ToString() method will output the query:

```
dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext();

var query = from c in db.Customers
                    where c.Name == "foo"
                    select c;

Response.Write(query.ToString());
```